# Rotation in opengl

Tags: opengl, transformation

I have a plane and I want to rotate it around the y axis. The planes coordinates are in:

```
Vec4f(-1,-1, -5, 1),
Vec4f( 1,-1, -5, 1),
Vec4f( 1, 1, -5, 1),
Vec4f(-1, 1, -5, 1),
```

I just want the plane to rotate, not go around in circles, so I translate it back to origin a then do the rotation:

```
glTranslatef(0,0,-5);
glRotatef(50.0*t, 0, 1, 0);

draw(plane);
```

But the plane still makes a circle around the origin. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Transformations apply in the opposite order in which you multiply them, also you might want to translate back to where it came from. So change it like this:

```
translation = -5;
if(translate_back) glTranslatef(0,0,-translation);
glRotatef(50.0*t, 0, 1, 0);
glTranslatef(0,0,+translation);
```

Comment: Thanks, it works, but one more question, when I move the plane back to origin I do glTranslate(0,0,5) not glTranslate(0,0,-5), so the code becomes:

glTranslatef(0,0,-5);
glRotatef(50.0*t, 0, 1, 0);
glTranslatef(0,0,5);

Comment: Just translate_back=true in above code, then you have your answer :)

Comment: Sorry, I misread your original code, I didn't see that you had your plane at z=-5. (I was thinking of z=+5). Of course with z=-5 then you are right. Changed the code for generability.